# How to add custom tooltips to Candlechart(Google Charts)

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have data coming from a **spreadsheet** of **Google Docs** and use **Candlechart** to display data via **JavaScript** How can I customize the tooltips?

I do not construct data with `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable` or similar constructor, so how do I achieve custom tooltips ?

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content) from Google explains how you can do this. At the bottom of the page it says [CandleStickChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/candlestickchart) is supported.

Comment: I have read through google docs before asking the question a lot. So I would like clear directions in case this is the answer :).